# Isolating php from accessing other mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, virtualhost

I've discovered that apache2 is able to "isolate" php from accessing to other , not specified, directories using this rule in virtual host:

php_admin_value open_basedir /path/to/your/virtualroot:/some/other/path

**Now i need to restrict also mysql access for that specific virtualhost to a specific database**. I would avoid just user/password to protect them to avoid bruteforce.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only restrict it per user. For example you can restrict the access through the mysql user and use the specific user for the domain (/VirtualHost).

I usually create a mysql user and give it access to all databases that have that username as a prefix:

```
CREATE USER 'someuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';
GRANT ALL ON `someuser\_%`.* to `someuser`@`localhost`;
```

So `someuser` is going to have full access to all databases that start with: `someuser_`. (for example: someuser_wordpress, someuser_drupal, etc...). User only see the databases, they have permission to.

You can also restrict the access to a single database as well:

```
GRANT ALL ON `databasename`.* to `someuser`@`localhost`;
```